# How to subscribe to MatCalendar activeDate variable? To show month and year labels of current active date in template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I am new to Angular.I am trying to build a datepicker with custom header.I passed custom header for mat-calendar component.
Reference:
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-calendar-header

Now I am struck at this point where I want to display current active Date's month in the header.

**.html

```
{{ monthLabel }}
```

**.ts

```
monthLabel = this.getMonthLabel()
months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dev'];
private getMonthLabel(){
   return this.months[this.dateAdapter.getMonth(this.calendar.activeDate)];
}
```

When user selects a different month in datepicker, monthLabel is not getting updated. How to achieve this? I want to solve it using `| async` . Please can someone guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Why your code does not work:

You are calling the funciton `getMonthLabel()` exactly one time: When you are assigning the result to `monthLabel`.

Try the following:

```
  monthLabel$ = new Subject<string>()
  months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dev'];

  private setMonth(date: Date | null){
    this.monthLabel$.next(date ? this.months[date.getMonth()] : '');
  }
```

and in your HTML

```
{{ monthLabel$ | async }}
...
<mat-calender (selectedChange)="setMonth">
...
```